# Removing GPS data using from an image using Pillow and Piexif

Tags: python, image, exif, python-imaging-library

I am working on creating a tool to pull the exif data from an image and remove the GPS data. I use Pillow to read in the file. I then use the following function to extract the exif and remove the GPS data.

```py
def manipulate_exif(img, remove_gps):

    try:
        import piexif
    except ImportError:
        raise

    try:
        exif = piexif.load(img.info['exif'])

        if remove_gps:
            exif.get('GPS', None).clear()
            print '{}'.format(pprint.pformat(exif))

    except Exception:
        exif = {}

    return piexif.dump(exif)

from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('./IMG_0264.jpg')

# Creates Issue
exif_copy_bad = manipulate_exif(img, True)

# No issue
exif_copy_good = manipulate_exif(img, False)

img.save('./Test_Bad.jpg', 'JPEG', exif=exif_copy_bad)
img.save('./Test_Good.jpg', 'JPEG', exif=exif_copy_good)
```

When I use it with the `remove_gps` flag set to `False` the function works as expected. However when I set `remove_gps` to `True`, I get weird field overflow issues in some of the fields and I get `Bad IFD1 directory` error in the exif file where the GPS data existed before.

I am not sure if this is a bug in Piexif or I am using Piexif incorrectly.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by *"pull"* and *"remove"*. Do you mean you want to pull the EXIF data out so that you get an image without EXIF data as your result, or you want to obtain the EXIF data and then do something else with it? Likewise do you want to obtain the GPS data for some other purpose, or do you mean you want to retain the EXIF data minus the GPS for some other use? Or do you want to get a new image with EXIF data but without GPS data as your result?

Comment: The Piexif library pulls the exif information and converts it into a dictionary. Remove means remove the GPS information. Pillow would otherwise remove the exif data so I need to use Piexif to convert it back to binary and append it to the image. I have added some code to hopefully clarify the issue.